# Advice on self studying abstract algebra from Dummit and Foote

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

I've found Dummit and Foote's abstract algebra quite challenging till now and I've occasionally required help from lectures on the web. Today I started reading the chapter on nilpotent groups and many things stood in my way but when I looked for lectures this time I could barely find any with most of the material in the book not even mentioned. So I started thinking about switching to Artin's book and using the Harvard University lectures on youtube. But they don't cover most of the topics.

Is there a book which is as comprehensive as Dummit and Foote's but a bit easier? Or maybe separate books that cover the same topics but are easier to follow? Please keep in mind  that not all topics have lectures available online and that I am self studying so there is no help. Also I don't ask questions here because they are so many and it would be extremely time consuming and ineffective to ask them one by one. So the best I can hope for is a book that I can follow with the number of things I don't understand  kept to a minimum so that I can either work them out myself or simple ask here.

To sum up, I simply want books that cover the various topics of abstract algebra and that are as easy to follow as possible

Comment: Nilpotent and solvable groups are not often material for a first abstract algebra sequence (even at graduate level, even at very good universities); they would normally show up on a second course on group theory, or a course devoted exclusively to group theory. Dummit and Foote, like Lang, aim to be far more comprehensive than is reasonable for a read-through by someone trying to learn the material from scratch. You should look for syllabi describing a good two-semester sequence in Groups/Rings/Fields, and look through just that material on the first go-around.

Comment: (One covers solvable groups in a first year graduate abstract algebra sequence mainly to discuss the application to solvability of polynomial equations, via Galois Theory; but the material in D&F is much more than that, and challenging on a first go-through)

Comment: Just stumble here when looking for hints on Dummit's Nilpotent :)) Just curious... did you manage to pass it already? Or did you find other book to help it? I like Dummit but hate it the way he skips things over. I tries other books, but find them too ignorant. So I'm also kind of stuck there. The chapter is written even worse than all previous 5 chapters. Try to get help from this forum, but it just got me banned from asking more questions, and now I'm wondering the way mathematicians run their own elite world :Pp Thanks anw.

Comment: I switched to Artin's book and went through the Harvard course. After finishing it (the book), I came back to Dummit and read the part on field theory and galois theory to consolidate my understanding of field theory and because I was interested in galois theory. Sadly, I had to skip the whole chapter "further topics in group theory" and take anything about solvable groups I encountered while studying galois theory for granted, it was mainly laziness to be honest, but things will go smoothly once you do that since they occur only in the final steps of proving the unsolvability of the quintic.

Comment: I came to believe that the chapter we are having trouble with isn't there to teach from scratch, it is a refresher at best.  I was focused on abstract algebra because I was mainly interested in group, ring and field theories and their applications in studying polynomials and their roots (solvability in radicals, factoring over fields..etc). Once I reached a satisfactory level of knowledge there, I switched to other fields of maths while doing my best not to forget what I learned. And to this day, the only things I know about solvable and nilpotent groups are the definitions :)

Comment: Don't be mad because you were banned from asking more questions, it takes time to get used to how you should ask questions here, I have my own "low-level" questions, I was bullied for asking them, I was mad at how they received the questions, but I could later see why they did that, the questions were so awkward :) Maths is difficult and it takes time to learn anything new, even participating in its open communities :)

Comment: (Also cc @ArturoMagidin) Thanks for the advise. I mainly come to the topic to support my study on physics. I expected to get some books as good as Feynman's Lectures, but realized it's too much a hope now. Books I encountered is assuming that all students want to become some skillful mathematicians, so they are kind of always pushing us to practice and find many obscure relations by ourselves. While what I want is to grasp the theorems just enough, not to rebuild the theorems (or one day my own theorems?). It's the same here I guess, they judge "too easy" questions harshly :D)